# html table content is misaligned when included

Tags: php, html, css

first of all I'd like to say that my english isn't very good, so forgive me for the errors, and let me know if I made something hard to understand...
I've created an internal search engine for my website with php/mysql, it works just as it should, and when it's alone it also looks fine
http://109.imagebam.com/download/WgEUwzfUPNYjIXIUnFDZww/35076/350755851/search.png

but when I include it in the homepage it change size and become misaligned
http://112.imagebam.com/download/xgrHs9O6HKt1nI404GNldg/35076/350755845/included.png

my question is, what I'm doing wrong and how i can fix it?

the form code is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="s" value="1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Cerca nel sito" name="ricerca" required></td>
                <td><input type="image" src="img/search.png" alt="Cerca"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

the homepage inclusion code is:

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="right">
        <?php
            include("search.php");
            include('contatti.php');
        ?>
        </div>
        other stuff
        </div>
```

and the divs css code is:

```
#content
{
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right:50px;
    min-width:1090px;
}

#right h1
{
    font-family:trajan pro,agency fb,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#555;
    padding:40px 0 0 30px;
}

#right h2
{
    padding:15px 10px 0 30px;
    font:13px normal trajan pro,agency fb,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:#3ba4c4;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#right p
{
    padding:10px 10px 0 30px;
}

#right
{
    width:280px;
    color:#000;
    float:right;
}
```

If something else is needed just let me know

Comment: Probably your div is inheriting some properties applied to elements like "p" and "input" or maybe browsers default setting. we may not be able to help you unless we have an example to debugg...

Comment: Make sure your css properties aren't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td><input type="image" src="img/search.png" alt="Cerca" align="left"></td>`

The table many times fails to fix and needs a little help.

Try with this